# How to set transparency only background?

Tags: android

[image]

This is one LinearLayout. I set this layout alpha to 0.6.

[image]

I want to set transparency only background, But it set inner values too.. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#33B99F">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/goBackButton"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="register(1/3)"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code.

Comment: @OussemaAroua Linearlayout's background is android Image. I set the android image to the background, and I want to put the value alpha "1.0". but because of parent's alpha is "0.6". so inner value's alpha is 0.6 too. I want to solve this error.

Comment: you need to set the background to transparency not the linearlayout it self

Comment: but linearLayout's background is `@mipmap/ic_luncher`. Where to put #80000000?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "#AAFFFFFF" on your layout background, or something like that. The first two values (AA in this case) represent the transparency. For more information take a look at the Color [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color).

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: If you want to keep the image, you can use a relative layout instead and set the background in it as I said, and then use a ImageView with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

Set background as #80000000. Hope it works

Comment: where?? LinearLayout's background is android image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<LinearLayout android:alpha="0.6"
android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#8033B99F">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="register(1/3)"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to make this color thicker than now, But #8033B99F is more lightly than now.

Comment: you have require more transparent

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5%  — 0D
0% —  00

Comment: #8033B99F this is 50% transparent bro

Comment: Oh. I mistake it. Thanks.  But still can't solve this problem. I put Linearlayout inside a LinearLayout. but because of parent LinearLayout's alpha is 0.6, so child LinearLayout's alpha is also 0.6. I want to set alpha 1.0 of child LinearLayout. and I want to set parent LinearLayout's alpha to 0.6

Comment: Sorry... I'm not fluent in English...

Comment: @SunSpike Did you get answer for this?
I have parent LinearLayout and 2 LL inside it. I want to set transparent to one layout

Answer (score 0):

dont set alpha for linearlayour because it contains another element so alpha will be applied to all the alement inside of linear layout so try to set background of linear layout onlu  like eg.  `android:background="#00ffffff"` to make any colour transperent add 00 ahead of any hex code

Comment: inside elements are transparent... I want to set element's color to 33B99F. but it seems like #6033B99F

Comment: just remove alpha from linear layout